# Brownian Motion, Probability of Hitting One Point Before Another when One of the Points is 0

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

The problem is...

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion starting at point $0$, let

$T = \inf \{ t > 1; B_t = 0$ or $1 \} $

be the hitting time of $\{ 0, 1 \}$ by $B_t$ after time $1$, and let $A = [B_1 \leq 1, B_T = 1]$ be the event that at time $1$, the Brownian motion is below point $1$ and then it will reach point $1$ before
reaching point $0$. Find $P_0(A)$.

At first glance, I thought this was an application of the following theorem...

"For a standard Brownian Motion, the probability that $a$ is first hit before $−b$ is given by

$p_a = \frac{b}{a + b}$ for $a > 0, b > 0$"

But this theorem is for points $a,b > 0$. Is the solution to the problem due to another version of this theorem? Or is it something completely different I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take #1.** Notice that $T\ge 1$. If someone came and told you $B_1=x$, then you could use the mentioned theorem from that point, right?

Additionally, $B_T - B_1$ is independent from $B_1 - B_t$ for each $t<1$.

---

**Take #2.** You may write

\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P_0(A) 
&= \mathbb P(B_T = 1, B_1\le 1) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^1\mathbb P(B_T = 1, B_1 = x)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^1\mathbb P(B_T = 1 \mid\ B_1 = x)\mathbb P(B_1 = x)dx.
\end{aligned}

Given the continuity of the Brownian trajectories and the mentioned theorem, you have
$$\mathbb P(B_T=1 \mid B_1 = x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0,\\
x & 0 < x < 1.
\end{cases}$$

Hence, you may compute

$$\mathbb P_0(A) = \int_0^1 x\mathbb P(B_1=x)dx = \int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt e}\right).$$

Comment: if we knew, say $B_1 = x$, then do you mean we are looking at the probability that it goes up 1-x steps before going down x steps? (i.e. 1 before 0)

Comment: Yup. Sorry for being so cryptic. I just had time to write a more detailed answer.